# Underscore doesn't work in Coffeescript's console

Tags: coffeescript, underscore.js

I've just started using Coffeescript and the Coffeescript console, and Underscore. However, whenever I define a function, Coffeescript decides that `_` means that function, and seems to forget the initial assignment of `_ = require 'underscore'`.

Why does this happen? How can I prevent it?
(I'd really like to be able to copy paste code from my files into the console.)

(Does `_` have some special meaning in the Coffeescript console? Does it mean "the last result" or something? That'd explain my issue?)

Details:

```
$ coffee 
coffee> _.contains [1, 2, 3], 3   # no Underscore, initially
TypeError: Cannot call method 'contains' of undefined
    at ...
coffee> 
coffee> _ = require 'underscore'
{ [Function]
  _: [Circular],
  VERSION: '1.3.3',
  forEach: [Function],
  ...

coffee> _.contains [1, 2, 3], 3    # now Underscore works fine
true
coffee> 
------> someFunction = (a, b) ->   # define a function ...
......>   a + b

[Function]
coffee> 
coffee> _.contains [1, 2, 3], 3     # now `_` is not Underscore any more!
TypeError: Object function (a, b) {    # Does `_` mean "last result" or sth?
  return a + b;
} has no method 'contains'
    at evalmachine.<anonymous>:3:7
    at Object.eval (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/coffee-script.js:142:17)
    at Interface.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/repl.js:131:40)
    at Interface.emit (events.js:67:17)
    at Interface._onLine (readline.js:162:10)
    at Interface._line (readline.js:426:8)
    at Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:603:14)
    at ReadStream.<anonymous> (readline.js:82:12)
    at ReadStream.emit (events.js:88:20)
    at ReadStream._emitKey (tty.js:327:10)
coffee> 
coffee> _ = require 'underscore'
coffee> _.contains [1, 2, 3], 3    # Now all is fine again, for a short while
true
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The CoffeeScript REPL has [this JavaScript](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/blob/1.4.0/lib/coffee-script/repl.js#L143) at its heart:

```
try {
  _ = global._;
  returnValue = CoffeeScript["eval"]("_=(" + code + "\n)", {
    filename: 'repl',
    modulename: 'repl'
  });
  if (returnValue === void 0) {
    global._ = _;
  }
  repl.output.write("" + (inspect(returnValue, false, 2, enableColours)) + "\n");
} catch (err) {
  error(err);
}
```

So if the last command returned something then `_` will be that something. I can't find any documentation about this though but searching for `_` isn't a terribly productive activity. If you want to use Underscore.js in the CoffeeScript REPL, you'll have to call it something other than `_`.

Thanks to [Trevor Burnham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/66226/trevor-burnham) (who wrote [the book](http://pragprog.com/book/tbcoffee/coffeescript) so I think we can trust him on this) we know that the CoffeeScript REPL uses `_` as the last result to match the behavior of the [node.js REPL](http://nodejs.org/api/repl.html#repl_repl_features):

> **REPL Features**
>   [...]
>   The special variable `_` (underscore) contains the result of the last expression.

Ruby's `irb` does the same thing.

Comment: Right, short answer: `_` does indeed mean "last result." This isn't documented very well, but it's done for consistency with the `node` REPL. Alas, this means that you'll have to map Underscore to some other identifier.

Comment: I think the best practice has been to use `__` (two underscores) for Underscore in the CoffeeScript REPL: `__ = require 'underscore'`

Comment: This is quite frustrating when copying/pasting existing code to the REPL. Best thing I've found is setting `__ = require "underscore"`, and then typing `__<enter>` in the REPL before whatever code you want to execute. (`__<enter>` will return underscore, so `_` will point to the underscore library for the next command that runs.)